# vba copy from word table to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to generate an excel file with 5 column from specific tables' cells in a word file (copy from word table to excel). My word file has 280 tables. I have no problem on addressing the cells that i want to copy from my word file. but i don't know why the result is an blank excel file. Maybe I'm wrong in the paste method uh i don't know... . This is my code:

```
Sub copyfromwordtoexcel()
    Dim exApp As Excel.Application
    Dim exDoc As Excel.Workbook
    Set exApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set exDoc = exApp.Workbooks.Add
    For xx = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(2, 2).Range.Copy
    exApp.Visible = True
    Cells(xx, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.Visible = True
    exApp.Visible = False
    ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(3, 2).Range.Copy
    exApp.Visible = True
    Cells(xx, 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    i = ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Rows.Count
    ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(i - 2, 2).Range.Copy
    exApp.Visible = True
    Cells(xx, 3).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.Visible = True
    ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(i - 1, 2).Range.Copy
    exApp.Visible = True
    Cells(xx, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.Visible = True
    ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(i, 2).Range.Copy
    exApp.Visible = True
    Cells(xx, 5).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.Visible = True
    exApp.Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some review, i;ve found that i shoud use pastespecial in my paste the corrected code is bellow

```
Sub copyfromwordtoexcel()
Dim exApp As Excel.Application
Dim exDoc As Excel.Workbook
Set exApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set exDoc = exApp.Workbooks.Add
For xx = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Columns.Count = 2 Then

ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(2, 2).Range.Copy
exApp.Visible = True
Cells(xx, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

Application.Visible = True
exApp.Visible = False
ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(3, 2).Range.Copy
exApp.Visible = True
Cells(xx, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
i = ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Rows.Count
ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(i - 2, 2).Range.Copy
exApp.Visible = True
Cells(xx, 3).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.Visible = True
ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(i - 1, 2).Range.Copy
exApp.Visible = True
Cells(xx, 4).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.Visible = True
ActiveDocument.Tables(xx).Cell(i, 2).Range.Copy
exApp.Visible = True
Cells(xx, 5).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.Visible = True
exApp.Visible = True
End If

Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Be careful when copying and pasting a table from Word to Excel.  If the cell in the table in Word has a new line character, then it will paste across two cells in Excel.  In Excel you will need to go into each cell using ActiveCell.formula=[value from Word table]

Comment: @psiphi75 Thank you. In that case i prefer to replace ^p first.