# How to extract data from word tables to excel 2011 using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to extract data (the information on the second column of word tables)  from multiple word documents and compile the data to one excel (2011 mac version). 
Below is the example: 
[the word table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubINE.png)

[the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgj2F.png)

I wrote a code, but this code doesn't work. How to revise this code so that it can work properly? thanks a lot!

```
    Sub extractdata()
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
r = 1
c = 8
Range(Cells(r + 1, ”A”), Cells(65536, c)).ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim filename As String, wdapp As Object, erow As Long, fn As String, arr As Variant
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application")
filename = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & “ \ " & " * .docx”)
Do While filename <> “”
        With wordapp.documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & filename)
            For i = 1 To 8
            arr = Left(.Table(1).Cells(i, 2))
            Next
            Cells(erow, “A”).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 8) = arr
        End With
    filename = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens instead of it working?

Comment: You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138958/vba-copy-from-word-table-to-excel and then just delete out the unnecessary first column.

Comment: it shows " compile error: invalid or unqualified reference" and in my code ".docx" is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub extractdata()

    Dim c As Long

    c = 8
    Range(Cells(r + 1, "A"), Cells(65536, c)).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim filename As String, wdapp As Object, erow As Long, _
    Dim fn As String, i as Long

    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application")

    filename = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.docx")
    Do While filename <> ""

        With wordapp.documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & filename)
            For i = 1 To c
                Cells(erow, i) = Left(.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2)).Range.Text
            Next
            .Close False
        End With

        filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```